# SQL Server date differences

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

How to find out total number of days from below table? I have tried with `DATEDIFF` function, but I cannot get my result.

```
date                      days 
-------------------------------
2017/11/10
2017/11/12
2017/11/15
```

Difference between days should be like

```
2017/11/12-2017/11/10, 2017/11/15-2017/11/12.
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Sql server 2005

Answer (score 2):

You could use `LAG` (SQL Server 2012 and above):

```
CREATE TABLE t(d DATE);
INSERT INTO t(d)VALUES ('2017-11-10'), ('2017-11-12'), ('2017-11-15');

SELECT *, DATEDIFF(day, LAG(d) OVER(ORDER BY d ASC),d)
FROM t;
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/VEMV61274)**

For SQL Server 2005 you could use:

```
SELECT s.*, DATEDIFF(day, s2.d, s.d) AS days
FROM (SELECT *,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY d) AS rn FROM t) s
LEFT JOIN (SELECT *,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY d) AS rn FROM t) s2
  ON s.rn = s2.rn+1;
```

**[Rextester Demo2](http://rextester.com/JGYJ11542)**